# TFS build Fails when Test projects containing MSCRM Organization service Url as localhost

Tags: tfs, dynamics-crm

I have a VM where MS CRM is installed and can be access using `http://localhost:5555/Orgname/main.aspx`.

I have created Unit test cases in my VM by refering the Organization Url as 
 `http://localhost:5555/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationService.svc?wsdl`

When I build the test project it connects to CRM and executes the test methods without any error.

Where as when I do a check-in ,the build is getting failed due to the reference to url "localhost".

for Build we have a separate Build server.

Can any one let me know how to solve this.

Answer (score 2):

Your tests are being executed on the build server and it looks like some of your tests are of the *Integration* kind and not of the *Unit* kind, as such it's looking for a configured CRM instance on that server (localhost resolves to the host itself for every machine), and can't find any. Which means you have a few options:

1. Install CRM on the build server, extend the build process to deploy CRM to the build server during build in order to run your tests. A build process like the one developed by [Wael Hamze can be extremely helpful for such a solution](http://waelhamze.com/2014/08/25/journey-to-implementing-continuous-delivery-for-dynamics-crm/).
2. Do not include a localhost address, but actually check in a location that points to a shared dev environment, the build server can connect to. This is not ideal, as the build may be dependent on specific data being present and concurrent builds may break due to strange interactions. If you configure the build agent to only run 1 concurrent builds, it may work.
3. Disable the tests that depend on an installed version of CRM. You could put a `[TestCategory("Integration")]` on these tests and then set a [filter condition on the build to exclude this test category](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286683.aspx).

Or you could try to improve your tests by making them independent of your configured instance, using Fakes or any other mocking framework. There are several [testing frameworks specifically made for CRM workflow activities](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/49e90766-d16d-41b6-8f01-12733a0c27ba) and other parts specific to CRM.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the Integration Test from the list of Unit Tests that are executed as part of the build. I recommend creating a new project called [projectundertest].IntegrationTests and adding all your integration tests there. Then configure the build to only execute UnitTests...

You build server is trying to execute all of the tests in your solution. Unfortunately you have an Integration Test masquerading as a Unit Test. When it is executed the test tried to access CRM and fails. This is correct behavior.